# Mongodb Aggregate Spanning multiple collections, Grouping and counts

Tags: mongodb

thanks for even looking at this.
Alright, so I have collections `conversations` and `chats`

`conversations looks as so`

```
{
 "_id": {"$oid":"5edfb91bd0f6230017a3b9da"},
 "participants":["dd1719e9-fabd-4ba8-879a-f1a592257cae", "a18b24f6-7f50-46aa-ac85-80b9f99bc789"],
 "creator":"a18b24f6-7f50-46aa-ac85-80b9f99bc789",
 "deleted":false,"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}
}
```

`chats` then looks as so

```
{
"_id":{"$oid":"5eb3eb134996aa23906dffe7"},
"seen_by":["9ef72407-9326-408d-911c-b0d0388eeefb","9ef72407-9326-408d-911c-b0d0388eeefb"],
"conversation_id":"9ef72407-9326-408d-911c-b0d0388eeefb",
"deleted":false,
"message":"i said looor you",
"date":{"$numberDouble":"1588849427302"},
"sender_id":"9ef72407-9326-408d-911c-b0d0388eeefb","__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}
}
```

Copied directly from Mongodb Atlas.

So from this, I want to be able to get conversations a user is on, that is, user's id is in the participants list in the conversation document. Then move on to get the last message with each conversation id, I am already achieving this using the sorting by date in descending order.

Well it doesn't stop there, I want to also get the most recent message whose `seen_by` property doesn't contain the users id and from there obtain the count of messages whose `date` is `$gt` that of the most recent unseen message (which implies that the user hasn't seen these messages).

At the end of the day, I want to return a list as so:

```
{
 ...
 last_message: { ... },
 unread_messages: 5,
 first_unread_message: { ... }
```

}

For getting conversations, and last_message, this is what I did.

```
this.model.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      participants: userId,
    },
  },
  { $sort: { last_activity: -1 } },
  { $limit: 10 },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "chats",
      let: { cid: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: ["$conversation_id", { $toString: "$$cid" }],
            },
          },
        },
        { $sort: { date: -1 } },
        { $limit: 1 },
      ],
      as: "last_message",
    },
  },
]);`
```

Hopefully somebody can relate to my use case/problem. Thanks in advance.